# Calling private method in BaseClass from a derived class with Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, typebuilder

I'm looking for a way to call a private method from a base class in a derived classes with the TypeBuilder. I know this can be done by simply invoking the method via reflection but attempting to call a passthrough method generated with the typebuilder results in a MethodAccessException. Has anyone found a way around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "issue". You're not allowed to call private methods - that's why they're private. The fact that you can do so with reflection when you've got suitable trust is effectively a backdoor, not an indication that it's something you should be able to do in other ways.

If at *all* possible you should redesign to avoid the desire to call the private method. If you absolutely *have* to call it, use reflection - the fact that that's ugly is an indication that you're in an ugly situation.

Comment: This idea came from a need to quickly get legacy code under unit test without the need for immediate redesign. I am well aware that this functionality breaks encapsulation and didn't mean to refer to it as an issue, I was just curious to see if it was possible.

Comment: @dSquared: If it's for testing (so your legacy code is under your control) I'd consider making it an `internal` method (with some indication that it would normally be private) and then use `InternalsVisibleTo` to get access to it from the test assembly.

Comment: That, along with keeping methods protected (derive and call in test class) are two solutions that I frequently use and seem to work very well. I guess I was just looking for a way around changing access modifiers to accommodate testing.